# API Get by string

Tags: c#, postgresql, api, get, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to get all data from db when a word matches a table field.
I've tried using a parameter in the http direction (GetRutaByText), like this
`.../api/ruta/GetRutaByText/'var'` and
`.../api/ruta/GetRutaByText/var`
both return empty, not error, but empty.
I also tried sending the "var" text from body (GetRutaByText2)

Interphase

```
    Task<IEnumerable<Ruta>> GetRutasByText(string value);
    
    Task<IEnumerable<Ruta>> GetRutasByText2(Ruta ruta);
```

Repository:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Ruta>> GetRutasByText(string value)
            {
                var db = dbConnection();
                var sql = @"select *
                            from public.tb_ruta
                            where descrip ilike '%@Value%'";
                return await db.QueryAsync<Ruta>(sql, new { Value = value });
    
            }
    
            public async Task<IEnumerable<Ruta>> GetRutasByText2(Ruta ruta)
            {
                var db = dbConnection();
                var sql = @"select *
                            from public.tb_ruta
                            where descrip ilike '%@descrip%'";
                return await db.QueryAsync<Ruta>(sql, new { ruta.descrip });
            }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet("{value}")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetRutaByText(string value) 
            {
                return Ok(await _rutaRepository.GetRutasByText(value));
            }
    
            [HttpGet]
            public async Task<IActionResult> GetRutaByText2([FromBody] Ruta ruta) 
            {
                return Ok(await _rutaRepository.GetRutasByText2(ruta));
            }
```

This are the results of the postman test
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCILP.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnaHR.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwaeX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,you need to change `ilike` to `like` in your `sql`.And then you need to debug and check if you get value in your action.Here is a demo to get value in api.

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class RutaController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("GetRutaByText/{value}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetRutaByText(string value)
        {
            return Ok(value);
        }

        

    }
```

result:
[image]

Last but not least,you need to be clear about the usage of `like`.

`...descrip like var` means descrip needs to be `var`.

`...descrip like var%` means descrip starts with `var`.

`...descrip like %var` means descrip ends with `var`.

`...descrip like %var%` means descrip have `var` in any position.

So maybe your db don't have a `Ruta` which descrip is `var`.

**Update:**

Try to use

```
return await db.QueryAsync<Ruta>("select * from public.tb_ruta where descrip ilike %"+value+"%");
```

Comment: I'm using ilike because I need it to ignore upper or lower cases.
I am aware of the use of like and %, and it's correct as to what I'm looking for, that has var in any position, and there are several entries in Ruta that have "var".
I'll check on the [HttpGet("GetRutaByText/{value}")], I think my error might be here. Thanks

Comment: Just checked and nope, it not working, plus in your example shows 200 OK, which mine does too, just doesn't bring back any values

Comment: If you try to use `return await db.QueryAsync<Ruta>("select * from public.tb_ruta where descrip ilike %"+value+"%");`,can it work?Maybe '' outside `%@Value%`  lead to the result.

Comment: heeey yess that worked!!! for both, from body and from uri

Answer (score 1):

Workaround that works propused by Yiyi You:

Using as following:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Ruta>> GetRutasByText(string value)
        {
            var db = dbConnection();
            return await db.QueryAsync<Ruta>("select * from public.tb_ruta where descrip ilike '%" + value + "%'", new { Value = value });

        }
```

Instead of:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Ruta>> GetRutasByText(string value)
        {
            var db = dbConnection();
            var sql = @"select *
                        from public.tb_ruta
                        where descrip ilike '%@Value%'";
            return await db.QueryAsync<Ruta>(sql, new { Value = value });

        }
```

Comment: If my answer is helpful,can you mark it as answer?Thank you.